# How to export an object from a separate file to both Node and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I have a file called `utils.js` which has some constants and I'm building a socket app which uses Node for backend work and regular Javascript for frontend. The names of the socket events are identical in both frontend and backend so I want to use the constants both in backend and frontend. But the syntax for exporting/importing is different in ecmascript6 as opposed to Node so how do I pull this off?

This is the contents of `utils.js`:

```
const EVENTS = {
    CONNECTION: 'connection',
    MESSAGE: 'message'
};
Object.freeze(EVENTS);
module.exports = EVENTS;
```

Comment: Object.freeze returns a freezed object, doesn't change the object passed, change it to `module.exports = Object.freeze(EVENTS);`.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro no

Comment: You can use ECMA6 Modules on node.js, [take a look](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the objects in JSON file, like *events.json*, or even *event.js* is you want plain JS objects. Both the Node and JS have access to this. Then you require/import this file in *utils.js* and you can do the same on the front end. Front and back ends can handle these however they want.

Comment: but don't I need to export that file first?

Comment: No, you would create a file that has that data in it, as a json file for example. Your Node or JS code fetches that JS code and then uses it as a JS object.

Comment: Did you mean to use a file read call in order to read the JSON file?

Comment: Sorry. On the client you'll need to load it in. This will be the client loading in a server file so it will need to load it with AJAX. This may be a problem in dev as sometimes there are difficulties loading local files as AJAX, but you can set up a simple http file server to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept your answer. Please edit it with exact code snippet that shows how to accomplish what is stated in the OP. Your suggestions are too vague.